# How can I create a list of structures automatically with R?

Tags: list, r, structure

Lets say that RES is a list with capacity for 1000 structs that function kmeans generates as output.

**How do I declare RES?**

After having RES declared I want to do something like this:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  RES[i] = kmeans(iris,i)
}
```

Thank you.
Rui

Answer (score 4):

If you use the R apply idiom, your code will be simpler and you don't have to declare your variable in advance:

```
RES <- lapply(1:3, function(i)kmeans(dist(iris[, -5]),i))
```

The results:

```
> str(RES)
List of 3
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ cluster     : Named int [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ centers     : num [1, 1:150] 2.89 2.93 3.04 2.96 2.93 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "1"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ totss       : num 55479
  ..$ withinss    : num 55479
  ..$ tot.withinss: num 55479
  ..$ betweenss   : num 4.15e-10
  ..$ size        : int 150
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ cluster     : Named int [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ centers     : num [1:2, 1:150] 0.531 4.104 0.647 4.109 0.633 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ totss       : num 55479
  ..$ withinss    : num [1:2] 863 9743
  ..$ tot.withinss: num 10606
  ..$ betweenss   : num 44873
  ..$ size        : int [1:2] 51 99
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ cluster     : Named int [1:150] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ centers     : num [1:3, 1:150] 3.464 0.5 5.095 3.438 0.622 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ totss       : num 55479
  ..$ withinss    : num [1:3] 2593 495 1745
  ..$ tot.withinss: num 4833
  ..$ betweenss   : num 50646
  ..$ size        : int [1:3] 62 50 38
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
```

Comment: Nice!:) 
However, I tried 

    RES <- sapply(1:3, function(i)kmeans(iris[, -5],i))

I got this error: Error: number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)

THanks

Comment: It's because you tried to cluster on `iris`, instead of a distance matrix.  Read the help for `?kmeans` and `?dist`.

Comment: Thank you Andrie. It was because of kmeans. Now your solution is working! I learned something important with sapply!

Answer (score 2):

I'll second that `lapply` is the right answer in this case.
But there are many scenarios where a loop is necessary, and it's a good question.

R lists don't need to be declared as empty ahead of time, so the easiest way to do this would to just 'declare' `RES` as an empty list:

```
RES <- list()
for (i in 1:1000) {
   RES[i] = kmeans(iris,i)
}
```

R will just extend the list for each iteration.

Incidentally, this works even for non-sequential indexing:

```
newList <- list()
newList[5] <- 100
```

yields a list with slots 1 through 4 designed as NULL and the number 100 in the fifth slot.

This is all just to say that lists are *very* different beasts in R than the atomic vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The way to create a list is unfortunately different from the usual way of creating a numeric vector.

```
# The "usual" way to create a numeric vector
myNumVec <- numeric(1000) # A numeric vector with 1000 zeroes...

# ...But there is also this way
myNumVec <- vector("numeric", 1000) # A numeric vector with 1000 zeroes...


# ...and that's the only way to create lists:

# Create a list with 1000 NULLs
RES <- vector("list", 1000)
```

So your example would become,

```
RES <- vector("list", 1000)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  RES[[i]] = kmeans(iris,i) 
}
```

(Note that kmeans doesn't like to be called with the iris data set directly like that though...)

But then again, `lapply` would do it too and in a more direct way as @Andrie showed.

Comment: In your example, we know that is the type "numeric"
I do not know what type is the kmeans function output. I guess it is something similar to a struct in "c". How can I turn around this? THanks

Comment: @Rui the output of `kmeans` is an object of class `kmeans`, which is essentially the same as a list.  So @Tommy's code will work (except that kmeans expects a distance matrix as input, not a data.frame).

Comment: @ Andrie, I never used kmeans with a distance matrix as input. I always used a data.frame. The sapply / lapply solution is very elegant. Thank you

Comment: @Tommy, It does not work.                                          RES[2] = kmeans(iris[, -5], 2) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
 The reason why I need this solution. Is because I will use foreach library parallelized through several cores.

Comment: @Rui - oops, should be a double-bracket assignment (`RES[[i]]`). I updated the code.